# Java Swing designer tool drag and drop components initialization confusion

Tags: java, swing

I am using IntelliJ to develop Java Swing. I drag and drop various UI components. I completely new in Java Swing. I might be asking very basic question.  So my confusion is that when I just pick any components and add them to the main form are those components initialized already or not. I saw that I get null pointer exception in my code:-

```
    public class MyForm {
    private JButton btnRead;
    private JComboBox cbCodes;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private DefaultComboBoxModel comboBoxModel;

    public MyForm(){
        comboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        cbCodes = new JComboBox(comboBoxModel); // Assignment to UI-bound field will overwrite field generated by UI Designer

        this.mainPanel.add(cbCodes);
     }
  }
```

I got warning as "Assignment to UI-bound field will overwrite field generated by UI Designer". And if I don't contract `cbCodes = new JComboBox(comboBoxModel);` I got null pointer exception. I am confused what do to? How to avoid the warning? Or do I just disregard the warning?

Comment: *"I am confused what do to?"* What I'd recommend is to put the GUI builder aside until you understand how to code a GUI in pure Java. Aside: After that, few people return to them.